# Modifier origin in Cordova places image too high up

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, famo.us

I am running the base famous app with the following code inside of Cordova 3.4.x
var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

```
var logo = new ImageSurface({
    size: [200, 200],
    content: 'img/famous_logo.png',
    classes: ['backfaceVisibility']
});
    var centerSpinModifier = new Modifier({
    origin: [0.5, 0.5]
});

mainContext.add(centerSpinModifier).add(logo);
```

For some reason setting the origin to `[0.5,0.5]` places the surface too high up. Is this a bug or do I need to redefine the origin somehow?

[image: Cordova Famous]

Comment: Your code checks out. Is there perhaps something in your CSS Class (backfaceVisibility) setting something off? And does it look okay when you run the same page in the browser rather than WebView?

Comment: no backface visibility is just backface-visibility: true. I think its the cordova wrapper I have